# how to use NVelocity from asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, nvelocity

I want to use "NVelocity" from plain ASPX pages without using any MVC framework. I don't want to use "NVelocity View Engine" thru' asp.net MVC framework. The only example that I got for "NVelocity" is for merging and writing onto console window (http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/usingit.html)

I am looking out for example on to integrating "NVelocity" into aspx web forms. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: You mean you want to use NVelocity *instead* of ASPX, in WebForms, right?

Comment: I mean, I want to transform some *.html pages using NVelocity in my .net web application. There are other aspx pages in my web app which would function in normal way as asp.net engine processes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. The idea is the override Page.Render() method in an aspx page. Write the code in Render() method to transform the HTML template (I mean, *.html file or *.aspx file) using NVelocity. Pass HTMLTextWriter object while merging the template and context "template.Merge(context, writer);"

This will render the transformed HTML to web browser.